# WCF X509 getting "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority"

Tags: wcf, security

I'm developing a WCF web service in C#, and a test client to go with it. The web service is hosted in IIS on a server and the test client running on a desktop PC. I am able to make calls to the web service from the client using http, but now am trying to get it working with https and x509 certificates. When I try to make calls now, I get "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority '192.168.5.5'". Here is what I've done so far to try to get this setup:

Created a self-signed certificate and key to use as a certificate root:

```
makecert -n "CN=RootTest" -r -sv RootTest.pvk RootTest.cer
```

Created certificates/keys signed by the above root for the server and client:

```
makecert -iv RootTest.pvk -n "CN=ServerTest" -ic RootTest.cer -sky exchange -pe -sv ServerTest.pvk ServerTest.cer
makecert -iv RootTest.pvk -n "CN=ClientTest" -ic RootTest.cer -sky exchange -pe -sv ClientTest.pvk ClientTest.cer
```

Imported the RootTest.cer as a "trusted root" under "local computer" on both the server and client PC using MMC.

Created PFX files for the server and client certificate/keys:

```
pvk2pfx.exe -pvk servertest.pvk -pi "mypassword" -spc servertest.cer -pfx servertest.pfx -po "mypassword"
pvk2pfx.exe -pvk clienttest.pvk -pi "mypassword" -spc clienttest.cer -pfx clienttest.pfx -po "mypassword"
```

Imported servertest.pfx on the Server under "local computer", "personal" using MMC.

Imported clienttest.pfx on the client PC under "local computer", "personal" using MMC.

Referenced "ServerTest" as the certificate in web.config on the server:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="MyTestService.Service" behaviorConfiguration="MyTestServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="secureBasicHttpBinding"
              contract="MyTestService.Service.IServiceContract" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="myTestServiceBehavior" >
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        <serviceCredentials>
          <serviceCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" findValue="CN=ServerTest" />
        </serviceCredentials>
      </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="secureBasicHttpBinding">
         <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
         </security>
      </binding>
   </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Referenced "ClientTest" as the certificate in the app.config on the PC client:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://192.168.5.5/MyTestService/Service.svc"
            behaviorConfiguration="myTestClientBehavior"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="secureBasicHttpBinding"
            contract="MyTestService.Service.IServiceContract" />
</client>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="myTestClientBehavior" >
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" findValue="CN=ClientTest" />
        <serviceCertificate>
          <authentication revocationMode="NoCheck" />
        </serviceCertificate> 
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="secureBasicHttpBinding">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

What am I doing wrong or missing? Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

From the client system, use a browser (for example IE) to navigate to the endpoint where your WCF service is hosted. The browser should tell you the certificate is not trusted and why.
[image]

Then click 'Continue to this website' and view the certificate by clicking the 'Certificate error' in the navigation bar and click the 'view certificates' link.
[image]

The certificate view should also tell you why the certificate was not trusted.

Comment: Thanks. I did that, and the "Certificate status" shows "the certificate is ok." Strange thing is the displayed "certificate path" value is not the one referenced in my web.config file ("ServerTest"), but a different one on the server. I tried changing web.config to FindByThumbprint using the thumbprint of my desired "ServerTest" certificate, and the service still signs with the other certificate. I introduced a typo in the thumbprint value in web.config, and got the expected "Cannot find the X.509 certificate" error. There's no cert setup in code, it's all in web.config. Any suggestions?